# Putting a search bar on admin model Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I am new with python and django, i want to know how can i implement the admin search bar on my project model? i notice that the user model has it by default.

[image]

My code is below, after the makemigration command still no search bar i think i am missing something. sorry for the noob question.

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    search_fields = ('title', 'text', 'created_at',)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Just add "list_filter" to your admin class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `apps` `admin.py`

inside the class for which you are registering the model

add

```
search_fields = ['column_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

add search fields in admin file instead of models file